# Spring PlatformTransactionManager - concurrent transactions

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, transactions, jdbctemplate

I'm implementing a JDBC database access API (basically a wrapper) and I'm usnig Spring `JdbcTemplate` with `PlatformTransactionManager` to handle transactional operations. Everything looks ok, but I cannot understand how jdbcTemplate manage concurrent transactions.
I'll give you a simplified example based on the creation of students to make my point. Let's create 2 students, John and Jack. The first without erros and the seconds with one error, there's the steps and the code below.

- John starts a transaction
- Execute John insert without commit
- Wait for Jack insert
- Jack starts a transaction
- Execute Jack insert with an error (age as null but database required NON  - NULL)
- Rollback Jack transaction
- Commit John trasaction

**StudentDAO**

```
public class StudentJDBCTemplate implements StudentDAO {

   private DataSource dataSource;
   private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateObject;
   private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

   // constructor, getters and setters

  public TransactionStatus startTransaction() throws TransactionException {
      TransactionDefinition def = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
      transactionManager.getTransaction(def);
  }

  public void commitTransaction(TransactionStatus status) throws TransactionException {
      transactionManager.commit(status);
  }

  public void rollbackTransaction(TransactionStatus status) throws TransactionException {
      transactionManager.rollback(status);
  }

   public void create(String name, Integer age){
      String SQL1 = "insert into Student (name, age) values (?, ?)";
      jdbcTemplateObject.update( SQL1, name, age);
      return;
   }
}
```

**MainApp**

```
public class MainApp {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        // setup db connection etc

       StudentJDBCTemplate studentDao = new StudentJDBCTemplate();

       TransactionStatus txJohn = studentDao.startTransaction();
       TransactionStatus txJack = studentDao.startTransaction();

       studentDao.create("John", 20);

       try {
           studentDao.create("Jack", null); // **FORCE EXCEPTION**
       } catch(Exception e){
           studentDao.rollback(txJack);
       }
       studentDao.commit(txJohn);
    }
}
```

How `JdbcTemplate` knows that 1 transaction is ok but the other is not? From my undertanding, despite we have created 2 transactions, `JdbcTemplate` will rollback Jack AND John transactions, because query, execute and update methods does not require TransactionStatus as a parameter. That means that Spring jdbcTemplate only supports 1 transaction at time?!

Comment: Transactions are thread based, you have 2 threads, each threads have their own state.

Comment: I've updated the example, please check. Now I have only one thread, how jdbcTemplate knows wich transsaction to use on studentDao.create calls?

Comment: Your sample uses a single transaction and not 2. The second call to `startTransaction` will return the status for the already ongoing transaction. If you enable debug logging you will see that the second start result in a debug message stating that you are participating in an ongoing transaction. It will only start a new transaction if specified to do so with `REQUIRES_NEW` else there is a single transaction. You can only have multiple transactions if you use multiple threads.

Comment: Ok, now it make more sense. So what you are telling me is that I can have multiple threads with a reference to the same DAO (StudentJDBCTemplate in this case) and every query/update/etc execution will belong to a separated transaction since we call getTransaction at the beginning of the thread, right?

Answer (score 2):

All the operations in a single transaction are always executed as a single unit so either all will be committed or none.

If John starts a transaction which insert and then update then either both (insert and update) will succeed or none and will not be impacted by the transaction started by Jack.

Now how the concurrent transactions interfere with each other is controlled by isolation level i.e. how a transaction sees data modified by another concurrent transaction.

Comment: but how jdbcTemplate knows that update( SQL1, name, age) is within John or Jack transaction?

Comment: The concept is same when Jack and John submits the same form using different parameters. Server uses a separate thread to serve a each request.

Comment: Still don't answer my question. I've updated the example, please check. Now I have only one thread, how jdbcTemplate knows wich transaction must be used on studentDao.create calls